# Does it make sense to use RTP protocol for multiple streamers and single receiver?

Tags: streaming, rtp, rtcp

I am in a process of learning and trying to use the RTP/RTCP protocol. My situation is that there is 1 to n streamers and 1 (or potentially 1 to m if needed) receiver(s), but in a way that the streamers themselves do not know about each other (they cannot directly due to technical reasons, such as different network, limited bandwidth, etc...). So it is more like multiple unicast sessions, but the receiver actually knows about them all, collects data from all of them, it is just the senders do not know about each other .

Now reading about the protocol, it seems to me that huge portion of it is related to sending some feedback, collision detections, and so on. **So I have doubts, is RTP is really applicable in this case? Is is already used in this way somewhere?**

Seems to me it is still beneficial to collect statistic about data transfer that RTP provides (data sent, loss, times, etc...), it just feels the most of the protocol is sort of left out...

Also I have one additional question, going through the various RTP libraries, they all assume that sender will also open ports for receiving RTP/RTCP data, **does RTP forbid use of one way communication?** I mean application that would only stream the data, not expecting to receive anything back. The libraries (e.g. ccRTP) seem to assume both way communication only...

Answer (score 0):

RTCP is the protocol that provides statistics. The stream receiver (client) will send stats to the sender (server) via RTCP. I don't believe the client will get any statistic reports from the server.

There's nothing wrong with a single client receiving multiple unicast sessions from various servers.

RTP requires two way communication during the setup process. Once setup is complete and the play cmd is sent, it is mostly one way. The exception are the "keep alive" packets that must be sent to the server periodically (usually every 60 seconds or so) to keep the stream going. The exact timeout value is sent to the client during the setup process.

But if you implement your own RTP, there's nothing stopping you from having the server send the stream continuously without any feedback from the client. Basically it would be implementing an infinite timeout value.

You can read about all the details in the spec: [RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)